# Как периодически подключаться к файлу?

Tags: cron

Например, мне нужно подключаться к файлу http://site.ru/add.php каждые 3 минуты с помощью cron. Как прописать команду?

Comment: >man cron

разве не работает?
И вообще разве это имеет отношение к программированию?

Comment: @Barmaley, дело в том, что я вообще не понимаю как и что прописывать. Вот и хочу узнать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кроном пользоваться просто.

1. Запустить редактор: crontab -e
2. Добавить строчку: 3 *  *   *   *  root   ... (вместо ... - ваша команда)